# Can hudson be configured to continue rest of build steps if one fails?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I don't expect this to be useful in my day-to-day workflow, but when initially configuring projects for hudson there are times when I wish I could get it to try all the build steps - not just stop after the first failure.

Again, I am not advocating this for everyday use - just for configuration of the builds.  (One of my projects takes about an hour or so and I'd rather not have to iterate through fixing each build step independently - I would like to fix each of them in parallel.

So, is there a way to tell hudson to continue the build steps when one fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution right now is to modify each of your build steps to make sure they unconditionally return success, instead of an error code.

There is an open enhancement request to do exactly what you want in [HUDSON-4819](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-4819)

Comment: I understand.  I can't change MSBuild to return success though if it fails.  I guess I will just keep doing it the way I have been and wait for this change you linked to.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

This actually can be quite useful in a day to day workflow.  We use [Zed Builds And Bugs](http://www.ZedBuildsAndBugs.com/) and it has this feature.  For each build step, you simply toggle whether you want the build step to fail the build if it fails.  By default it is turned on (sensible).

Where this has come in handy are things like optional steps - e.g. copying final binaries to other distribution servers.  Sometimes these servers are up and sometimes not.  It doesn't really matter if this particular step fails, but when it does fail, I don't want the whole build to fail.